# Does Mongoose implement the $isolated operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Does Mongoose implement the [$isolated](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/isolated/) operator? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it does, just add it as parameter to your query as in the official documentation, it should work. 
Mongoose is actually a wrapper for the most common operations, but, at the same time, it can bypass what you send directly to the db. Then, you don't miss any feature from the db.